Prepositional phrase functioning as a direct object
In the following example:
I told my friend about the book
Is the prepositional phrase about the book functioning as a direct object? Or would it function as either an adjective or adverb.
For me, about the book is an adverbial modifying the verb to tell and giving us more information about what's being told.

No, it's not a "direct object". It's what you already said - an [adverb] prepositional phrase. A direct object woud be I told my friend the truth (my friend being the indirect object, that could itself be "prepositionized" as I told the answer to my friend).

Well, you could state, "I read Of Mice and Men." Admittedly, the title of a book is a proper noun, though a prepositional phrase. Then there's Burns' To a Mouse, None of these quite squeak by, though.

It's neither direct object nor an adjective or adverb. The PP "about the book" is complement of "tell", the verb that licenses it.

It doesn't make sense to think of it as a direct object. A direct object is a thing that receives the action of the verb. Like if you say, "I read the book", "the book" is the direct object because it is the thing being read. "Sally answered many questions", "many questions" is the direct object because it is what is being answered. Etc.
There may be cases where the idea of "receives the action" may be fuzzy. But I can't think of any sense in which "about the book" could be said to be receiving the action of "told". You could say, "I told my friend the title of the book." Then the thing that you told is "the title". But you wouldn't say that the thing that you told is "about the book". Maybe what you told is something about the book, but for that to make sense, there has to be a "something" in there.
